# Is it possible to access browsing history without permission?

Tags: browser, cookies, facebook, advertisements

It's kind of weird that whenever I search for something on Web or any other online retail store, etc for something, I soon see the very same as an advertisement on Facebook (The right side base).

If we search on Google, and observe relevant Google Ads on websites, that's understandable. Its Google Search - Google Ads interrelation.

What about Facebook and searching other sites? The only reasonable justification I see is that Facebook somehow reads my browsing history and then makes these relevant ads.

Comment: Most likely this is down to tracking cookies: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Tracking

Comment: as a preventive measure to protect privacy, you can probably use a separate browser only for browsing FB while your search in your default browser. also check these other alternatives http://lifehacker.com/5843969/facebook-is-tracking-your-every-move-on-the-web-heres-how-to-stop-it

Comment: Related: How Facebook Knows What You Looked at on Amazon - http://www.25hoursaday.com/weblog/2014/02/17/HowFacebookKnowsWhatYouLookedAtOnAmazon.aspx "Demand Side Platforms (DSP) give Facebok the unique identifier for an individual's browser as well as the cookie data containing the browser's history"

Answer (score 2):

It's not reading browser history. When you're logged into Facebook or Google you are universally logged in, allowing sites using Google and Facebook APIs to be logged to your account, when logged out they use tracking cookies(which can easily be removed from your system). [This](http://lifehacker.com/5843969/facebook-is-tracking-your-every-move-on-the-web-heres-how-to-stop-it) is a bit more specific on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

It's theoretically possible for them to gain access to your browser history; however, doing so requires either finding and exploiting a security hole (not likely, because even the most aggressive marketer can tell that that's an invitation for a lawsuit) or convincing you to run software written by Facebook.

More likely, what's going on is that they're using their own server logs.  Whenever your browser requests a file from a server, it will tell the server what the referring page is.

For example, on http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=8556476&csid=_61, there's the following remote Javascript:

```
<script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Visiting it generates the following HTTP request (unnecessary headers stripped out):

```
GET /translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit HTTP/1.1
Host: translate.google.com
Referer: http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=8556476&csid=_61
```

At this point, Google knows what page you were looking at and can theoretically tailor future ads accordingly.  Any Facebook-supplied share/like/connect buttons can do the same thing.

They can identify you through facebook logins (obviously), cookies, IP addresses, and browser fingerprinting.  While it's harder for them to be sure from IP or browser fingerprint alone that you're the same one who was looking at that particular page, they can make a reasonably good guess.  They could conceivably also buy logs from other companies, or make use of logs from companies they've bought that are not currently Facebook-branded.

It should also be noted that there are sometimes several layers of companies in the chain to get a single ad to your screen, and each of them has access to their own logs.  So if Facebook resells ad-space to Amazon, Amazon may be able to tell that you're the same person who was looking at banana slicers and remote-control tarantulas even if Facebook doesn't know that.